# Logs appending in http_access_.log in WSO2

Tags: wso2

How do I stop http_access logs appending  in http_access_.log in WSO2, not to be confused with http_access_(date).log?

I have tried to disable it by removing the property in catalina-server.xml, which stops appending in http_access_(date).log but not in http_access_.log

Comment: What's the product and the version? And did you change the catalina-server.xml file directly? Or did you change it in the deployment.toml file?

Comment: I implemented the change in wso2am-2.6.0. Yes,I did the change directly not in deployment.toml